# Can't update parameters i & j

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int rev(int& sourcenum)
{
    int temp = sourcenum;
    int sum = 0;
    while (temp!=0)
    {
        sum*=10;
        sum += temp%10;
        temp/=10;
    }
    return sum;
};

int main() {
    int i,j;

    cin >> i >> j;

    int add = rev(i)+rev(j);
    cout<<i<<" "<<j<<endl;

    cout<<add<<endl;
    cout<<rev(add);

}
```

In this code, I can't change parameters `i` & `j`. I Don't know why.

Comment: I'm confused - you don't try to update i, or j, or sourcenum

Comment: why `sourcenum` in `int rev(int& sourcenum)` is passed by reference? it is not modified. If you change it with `int rev(int sourcenum)` you can replace i at the call level by the result of a computation.

Answer (score 3):

In the first line of your `rev(...)` function, you are doing `int temp = sourcenum;`. This statement is copying over the value from the variable `sourcenum`, which you intentionally correctly passed by reference.
The problem is, that `temp` is now a **new** independant variable, just initialized with the value of the variable `sourcenum` you passed by reference. As such, if you change now `temp`, it won't affect the `sourcenum`.

As a minimal change suggestion: In case you change `int temp = sourcenum;` to `int& temp = sourcenum;`, you should get the result of changing the passed reference as expected.

Comment: @MoonJune: You need to regard, that your program flow logic was not corrected with my comment. To fix that `0 0` output, you need to adjust your condition `while( temp!= 0)` to be something else, as it will lead to the `0 0` output. I am not sure what you want to archieve with this code, but at least with my change `i` and `j` are changed afterwards. So, your questions regarding the pass by reference is solved. Debug your code and see how you change `sourcenum` during execution to check where you have a logical error.